# how to assign each element of a list to each element of another list?

Tags: python-3.x

```
l1=['img1','img2'] # a list has some names

l2=[[1,4,5],[6,3,1]] # another list has some array:
```

how can I assign `l1` to `l2`, so they will contain the corresponding value index-wise?
#I want them to be stored like it:

`img1=[1,4,5],img2=[6,3,1]`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary for this and store img1, img2 etc as keys and the corresponding values of L2 as values.

```
d = dict(zip(l1, l2))
```

Then, retrieve values by key, for eg:

```
d["img1"]
#this will output [1,4,5]
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to use them directly as variable assignments. For example, in my extended code, I want to multiply like this np. multiply(L1[0], L1[1]). It will multiply (img1,img2) with corresponding array value, while using dictionary is it possible?